# WAVE Non grouped dimension in a grouped query

Tags: einstein-analytics

I want to connect two datasets with each other to make a case on them.
However I can't group a dimension because it only exists in one dataset. This is the field on which we test the value for the case.

However because I can't group them, there comes an error on the screen that I can't use my dimension in the query.

Is there a way I can go around this problem and still use my dimension in my query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Busted my head with this...but I finally got it Working !!!!**

```
a = load "CAR_Contact";
b = load "CAR_Products";
a = group a by ('Client_Activity_Report__c', 'Contact__c.AccountId.Name', 'Client_Activity_Report__c.Owner_Sales_Region__c');
b = group b by ('Meeting_Details__c', 'Product__c.Boutique__c', 'Meeting_Details__c');
q = group a by 'Client_Activity_Report__c', b by 'Meeting_Details__c';
q = foreach q generate a.'Client_Activity_Report__c.Owner_Sales_Region__c' as 'Region', count('a') as 'Count';
r = group q by 'Region';
r = foreach r generate 'Region' as 'Region', count('q') as 'Count';
r = limit r 2000;
```

First Group The Data Sets individually, then Cogroup... (Need a bit more testing..)